# Theorem on bounds of prime counting function

Tags: number-theory

At page 65 of Rosemberger's book there is a proof that for any natural number x>=21:

$\pi(x)>\frac {lnx}{2lnlnx}$ where ln is the natural log.
The proof goes as follows:
For fixed x let $p_i$ run all over the primes less than or equal to x. Then from the FTA (fundamental theorem of arithmetic) the number of integral solutions to the inequality:
$$\prod_{\substack{p_i}}{p_i^{e_i}}<=x$$ for $e_i>=0$ is precisely x. Ok until now I have understood. Now I don't understand well this passage: on the other hand the number of solutions is the product of the number of choices for each $e_i$. What does it mean? Then since for a solution $p_i^{e_i}$<=x we have: 
$$e_i<=1+\frac{lnx}{lnp_i}<=1+\frac{lnx}{ln2}<(lnx)^{2}$$...now I don't understand why for x>20 we have that:
$$x<=\prod_{\substack{p_i}}{(1+\frac{lnx}{lnp_i})}$$?

Comment: @Peter for me mind-boggling

Comment: Suppose x=5 then solutions to the previous inequality are 2^0*3^0*5^0=1<=5, 2^1*3^0*5^0<=5...and so on...so the solutions are x=5?

Comment: I have an idea (perhaps) what is going on : For every prime upto $x$, an upper bound of the possible exponent is calculated. And the simple fact is used that the prime factors of $x$ cannot exceed $x$. The inequality $1+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}<(\ln x)^2$ holds for $x\ge 8$, maybe this is useful.

Comment: The book doesn't give any more remarks ?

Comment: @Peter for x=5 one solution is e1=0, e2=0, e3=1 p1=2 p2=3 p3=5 this should give e3<1+ln5/ln5, another solution is e1=2, e2=0 e3=0 p1=2 p2=3 p3=5 this should give e1<1+ln5/ln2...it seems that if you multiply togheter that ei you get precisely x

Comment: infact the book say something like the number x is the number of choices for every ei

Comment: for x=5 finally we have 5<=(1+ln5/ln2)*(1+ln5/ln3)*(1+ln5/ln5)

Comment: this implies also that (1+ln5/ln2)*(1+ln5/ln3)*(1+ln5/ln5)<((lnx)^2)^pi(x) where pi(x) is the prime counting function